# insertion picture in latex problem

Tags: floats, captions, labels

I'm using latex editor to insert a picture. When I view the output in pdf file the "Diagram.jpg" appear above the picture. How I can remove it?

the code written for insertion is:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{Blcok Diagram.jpg}
    \caption{Block Diagram}
    \label{fig:Block Diagram}
\end{figure}
```

and the output is like:

[image]

Comment: Remove that `Blcok ` from  `{Blcok Diagram.jpg} ` and make it `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Diagram.jpg} `

Comment: Don't use filenames/paths with  blank space.